# How to select one specific PID value if more than one process has a similar PID number in it?

Tags: linux, process, grep

I am using RHEL 7.5 and I have a Java program that includes a file with the PID number. If the process is killed, the file still exists and I am doing an script to validate if the PID that is stored into that file is alive or not but I have a doubt or problem.

The PID 445 exists and 2445 exists. So how can I only get the 445?

I tried with the following command:

```
ps -ax | egrep "^ 445"
```

But it didn't return anything.

The two process:

```
ps -ax | grep -v grep | egrep "445"

  445 pts/2    Sl     3:50 /opt/
 2445 ?        S      0:00 dbus-launch
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `-p`:

> `-p  proclist`
>   Write information for processes whose process ID numbers are given in `proclist`. […]

<sup>([source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html))</sup>

In your case:

```
ps -p 445
```

POSIX says `ps` should return positive exit status if "an error occurred". Every `ps` I tested considers `proclist` that doesn't contain at least one PID of an *existing* process as "erroneous". This is useful. Example:

```
ps -p 445 >/dev/null && echo "Process exists."
```

Notes:

- [PIDs of terminated processes may/will be reused eventually](https://superuser.com/q/135007/432690), so even if the PID is in use, it may not be the process you are interested in.
- If PID in the file comes from before the recent (re)boot, the process is obviously no more, even if the PID is now in use. (Hint: [configure the program so the file is on `tmpfs`](https://superuser.com/a/1418624/432690)).

Comment: Hello Kamil. great command unfortunately to me... I could use it into a script, thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a process is running in Bash scripts by using `kill -0` like this:

```
if [ -f ${pid_file} ] && kill -0 $(cat ${pid_file}) 2>/dev/null; then
  exit
else
  rm -rf ${pid_file}
  exit
fi
```

The `${pid_file}` equates to the file path with the PID in it. The `-f ${pid_file}` checks if the PID file exists. Then the `kill -0 $(cat ${pid_file})` checks if the process is running.

Which boils down to:

- If the process is running, just do nothing but exit the script.
- Else (if the process is *not* running, just remove the PID file.

The magic in the `kill -0` is explained on the man page for [`kill`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill):

> If *sig* is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a process ID or process group ID.

Comment: Hello JakeGould. Thanks for your comment but it didn't work, I had to create the following script and it works. #!/bin/bash

pid_file=/opt/program_name/file.pid
pid=`cat $pid_file`
val=`kill -0 "$pid"
if [ -f ${pid_file} ]; then
 if [ -n "${val}" ]; then
  echo "File exist and the PID si alive..."
  exit
  else
     echo "The file exist but the process doesn't exist..."
     exit
 fi
 else
    echo "The file doesn't exist..."
fi
Thanks for your help it was useful to create this little script.

Comment: @JosePerez Glad I was able to help in some way. If my answer helped you, please be sure to upvote it. And if it’s the answer that ultimately solved your issue, please be sure to check it off as such.